# Python: 'module' object has no attribute 'logout_view'

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to implement the ability to log out into my django site and I'm getting the following error when attempting to use the command python manage.py runserver while in the virtual environment:

```
(ll_env) C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000006693BA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\me\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\learning_log\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "c:\users\me\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\learning_log\users\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logout_view'
```

This is my urls.py file in the learning_log\users directory:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Login page
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    # Logout page
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    # Registration page
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

The most recent addition to the above file was:

```
    # Logout page
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
```

The following code was added onto the end of my views.py file as the most recent addition:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    """Log the user out."""
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))
```

This is my base.html file:

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello, {{ user.username }}.
    <a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">log out</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
  {% endif %}
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

This was the most recent addition to my base.html file:

```
    <a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">log out</a>
```

The code worked fine before the additions mentioned above. Knowing me it's probably an easy fix, but does anybody have a solution for this issue? I'm currently using Django 1.11.7 and Python 2.7.14.

Comment: The problem might be in the import line `from . import views`. Is the views.py in the same app as urls.py?

Comment: A different urls.py file exists in the same directory as views.py, but all of the files are contained within the same app from the looks of things. The folder which contains all of my files is named learning_log. Within the folder is everything I need for this whole ordeal, including two folders; the former is named learning_logs, the latter is named users. The former contains the views.py file as well as the other urls.py file which is responsible for the ability to work with topics & entries on the site. The latter contains the urls.py file I mentioned in my original post & a blank views.py.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a relative import in `users\urls.py`

```
from . import views
```

This is equivalent to

```
from users import views
```

However, it sounds like your `logout_view` is in `learning_logs\views.py`. If that is the case, then you should change the import to

```
from learning_logs import views
```

Note that Django has a `logout` view, so you don't have to write your own. Change your import and URL pattern to:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
```

Then set [`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url) in your settings so that Django redirects to the index after logging out the user:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'learning_logs:index'
```